# SHA2 P12/pfx cert

Tags: cryptography, certificate, ssl-certificate, pkcs#7, pkcs#12

I have a certificate in a `.PEM` file and a key.

The signing algorithm of the certificate file is `SHA256WithRSAEncryption` but when I create a p12/pfx file using the certificate file and the key the Signature Algorithm of p12/pfx file changes to 
"PKCS7 Encrypted data: `pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC`, Iteration 2048"

Is there a way I can get a SHA-2 certificate after the process?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate lists the algorithm used to sign the certificate, while the PKCS#12 store lists the method that was used to encrypt the key / certificate store.

PBE stands for Password Based Encryption, and the SHA-1 is only applicable to the way the password is transformed into a key; it has *nothing* to do with the certificate itself. The same certificate is still in the store if everything went well.

Notes:

- Also in there is 40 bit RC2 and a low iteration count; this provides next to no security. So if you're using this to protect the private key you'll have to start over again;
- The RSA key pair for the certificate can be used to perform signature generation / verification with *any* hash algorithm (if non-repudiation or authentication is compatible with the key usage of the certificate), not just the one used to *sign the certificate itself*.

Comment: Psychic debugging says the PFX was created by OpenSSL and the 40-bit RC2 is the encrypted certificate (encrypted private key would be 3DES, for reasons).